# Should sum of sample weights always be equal to the target population

Tags: sampling, weights, calibration

I have a simple question regarding sample weighting:

From what I understand, sample weights are used to reduce or eliminate potential biases arising from the differences between the selected sample and the target population. However, there are different sources for these biases, such as unequal selection probabilities across strata in stratified random sampling and non-response.

In formulating sample weights, it usually involves calculating base weight, non-response weight and calibrating weight to align weighted sample distribution with population distribution. I am wondering, after these calculations, should the sum of sample weights always be equal to the total number of units in the target population? It seems from some practical examples, after weight adjustment (calibration), the sum of sample weights differ somewhat from the number of total population.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to trimming, it's quite possible with cluster sampling or multistage sampling that the target population size is not known. You might not know the size of clusters you don't sample.  The weights should then add to an unbiased estimate of the target population.

Also, there might be more than one relevant population size. For example, in a survey that samples households or dwellings to recruit people, the household-level or dwelling-level weights might sum to the number of households/dwellings in the population, but the sum of person-level weights might not be be population size for people.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may find the answer: sometimes weight trimming can lead to that the sum of sample weights is not equal to the total number of population. In this case, weight normalisation can be applied to align the two. Reference: https://docs.wfp.org/api/documents/WFP-0000121326/download/